# Submit values from table not working properly after filtering data

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table which has a form in it, with each row containing a column where the value can be changed from a drop-down box. On clicking the 'Save changes' button, all the rows will be updated with the new values.

[image]

The form/table works as intended in normal cases. But if I use the search functionality of the bootstrap table to filter out a few of the rows and then try to update rows with the values, the wrong rows are getting affected.

So from the example in the above image, if I filter out to view just the second row like in the picture below, then the changes, or the 'Update' query is executed on the actual first row, that is to the row which had 'Bob' as the 'technician'.

[image]

I'd like to know how to solve this issue.

Here is the relevant code:

```
foreach($tickets as $tickets)
{
    $users = $app['database']->selectAll('users');
    echo ("<input type='text' style = 'display:none' value = '$tickets->id' name = 'ticketid[]'>");
    echo "<td class = '$technician->color'>$technician->name</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<select name = "user[]" id="user" class="form-control">';
    echo "<option value = $technician->id>$technician->name</option>";
            foreach($users as $users)
            {
                echo "<option value = $users->id>$users->name</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

For the database part, I am calling a function `transferTask` which accepts first the table name, then two arrays, one array containing updated usernames from the dropdown fields and one containing corresponding ids.

```
transferTask('tickets', $user[$i], $ticketid[$i])
```

The above function is executed for each row in the table. I think it's an issue wit the name array being passed from the form to this function but I'm not sure. Help is appreciated!